# How to delete temporary ASP.net files in a production environment?

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I have deployed a new build on Production server, but I dont see the change in this version. I found out that it was caused due to old version of the DLL file under the temporary ASP.net folder

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

In DEV environment, I can delete, but in Prod. I have restricted access to delete files inside the ASP.net temporary folder.

Can anyone tell me how can I get the new DLL files recreated immediately after I deploy the new files?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "restricted access" do you mean you are forbidden by account permissions or that when you try to delete them you get an in use type error message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you add new DLLs to the bin folder, they should immediately overwrite the files in the ASP.NET temp folders. I have myself noticed that sometimes (I assume that happend becuase of concurrency issues) the dlls are not loaded into memory.

If you have access to IIS management console, you could **recycle the worker process**. That should ensure that new temp assemblies are loaded.

Also if you change aspx oder ascx files, the resulting assemblies should be automatically replaced in the temp folder. If there is the same problem, I recommend recycling the worker process. Maybe you can integrate this in some automated way in your deployment procedure.