# Application Error on the prod

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a6f9ad3e\7d6f22eb\App_Web_ckcrdejl.4.cs    Line: 0
```

I am keep getting this error when i try to post the data into the database in production server

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" get in multiple ways...  normally it raise error msg for reteiving null values.. Pls check tht..

Comment: have you tried removing temp asp.net files?

Comment: Yes  Șhȇkhaṝ i had removed the temp file

Comment: does your web.config file at local machine has some keys that is not present in production server's web.config?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224823/how-to-delete-temporary-asp-net-files-in-a-production-environment

Comment: I recycle the worker process but keep getting the error.

Comment: Attach a debugger and take a looksee.